# How do you test a class that reads from multiple files with pytest?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I'm trying to write a test for the following class which has a method that reads from two different files?

```
# example.py
class Example
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def load(self):
        p = open('p.txt').read()
        q = open('q.txt').read()
        return p + q
```

I would like to test the `load` method by supplying the contents for both files:

```
# test_example.py
from lib import Example

def test_example_class():

    p_contents = 'abc'
    q_contents = 'def'

    # What do I put here to mock the open function for both files?

    ex = Example()
    assert(ex.load() == p_contents + q_contents)
```

How do I supply the contents of the two files as they don't (and cant exist) in the test environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly. You have a method that reads two text files and concatenates their contents. In your case, you want to test the concatenation. The thing is if you want to test that you need to decouple the process made to your function. Your function is doing 3 things currently:

- It opens a text file with function `open`
- It extracts the content with the method `read`
- It concatenate two contents from two different text files.

The goal of your test is to test the last step of your function. And you do not want to create dummy text files. So, the only option that I can think of is to decouple your method into two methods:

- `_read_file` performs the first two steps, it will be monkey patched in your test.
- `load` your original function that performing the three steps.

I suggest the following code:

```py
class Example:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  @staticmethod
  def _read_file(file_path: str) -> str:
     return open(file_path).read()

  def load(self):
    p_text = self._read_file("p.txt")
    q_text = self._read_file("q.txt")
    return p_text + q_text

# Then you monkey patch your class (you can also just edit the object in this case).
def _monkey_read_file(file_path: str) -> str:
  return "abc" if file_path == "p.txt" else "def"
Example._read_file = _monkey_read_file

example = Example()
assert(example.load() == "abcdef")
```

There could be some substantial improvements for this test but I think it goes beyond the scope of your question.

This simple decoupling is robust since you can test each step. If, later, you want to test the reading, you can test the `_read_file` method alone.